# Etymology of お負け

Tags: usage, etymology

In my flashcard studying of JLPT1 vocabulary I've across お負け with three English definitions (from JMdict):

1. *freebie*,
2. *price reduction*,
3. *exaggeration*.

Now my question is how adding an honorific prefix to 負け (*loss*, *defeat*) has come to mean something positive (well, at least for the receiver). Is it because someone concedes something to someone else? E.g. a salesperson conceding a customer a reduction in price.

And what about the third definition, *exaggeration*, which seems unrelated the first two? As JMdict does not provide a sample sentence for this definition I'd be grateful if someone could provide one.

よろしくお願いします。

N.B. I am unfamiliar with the tags of the site, so moderators are free to add additional ones.

Comment: Nice question! I've also pondered this one. My guess would be that the "seller" is taking a "loss" in the transaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leo's guess is actually right. For reference, it is enough to go on the wikipedia page of [お負け](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%91).

The meaning originally comes indeed from the fact that the seller is losing something in the bargaining process (from wiki):

> おまけの語源は「御負け」の文字通り、店員が客との駆け引きに負けて値を下げる行為を指す言葉であったが、のちに商品以外の物品を追加する行為なども言うようになった.

Comment: Simple as that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any straightforward uses for お負け as "exaggeration", but it could be used like this:

> 彼の話にはいつもなんらかのお負けが付いている

```
"There's always a little something more to his stories"
```

This *might* imply an exaggeration...

Sidenote: おまけ can also mean menstrual cycle

Comment: `おまけ can also mean menstrual cycle` ← 初耳です。最近の新しい俗語的な用法でしょうか。

Comment: 女房詞だそうです。。。http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%91

Comment: 室町時代(500年以上前)の俗語…w

Comment: 時代劇に出てくることはあるかな？

Comment: いやー、出てこないと思います。たぶんほとんど誰も知らないので…

Comment: 「負け」からの言葉でしょうか？語源が他にあるなら本題と関係ないかもしれませんね。weblioで引いたら一番トップに出る項目だったのできっと関係があるだろうと思っていました。

Comment: 「任{ま}く」という古語もあるようです。http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%8F　たくさん他の「まく」もありますね。。。語源って深い深い

Comment: Thank you for the sample sentence, it makes sense now as "laying it on thick" or "adding a little extra/something". I'll steer clear of that alternative usage though ;-)